# How to use Web OTP API

Tags: android, google-chrome, one-time-password

Web OTP API (as described here: https://web.dev/web-otp/) used to work.

But now even the demo link on this page is not working for me.

I get the permission dialog, but the Promise never gets resolved or throws.

```
    navigator.credentials.get({
      otp: { transport:['sms'] },
      signal: ac.signal
    })
```

I've been scratching my head for a while. Tried re-implementing it, using different formats for the OTP SMS. But still getting the same. I tried two separate Android phones both running Chrome 100 on Android 10.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: Please check your sms format and that it complies with the @hostname #code
It is important that the hostname is the same where the input lives, if its a subdomain it wont work, as it results in the exception: DOMException: OTP retrieval was cancelled.